# Setting alpha as an array in plt.imshow() makes the plot crashe

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, anaconda, conda

When trying to run this little piece of code inspired from the matplotlib documentation [Blend transparency with color in 2-D images](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_transparency_blend.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-image-transparency-blend-py):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test = np.random.random((300, 300))

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(test, alpha = test/test.max())
plt.show()
```

I end up with :

```
<matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0x7f8bfe8cc610>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/darkvador/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py", line 508, in _draw_idle
    self.draw()
  File "/Users/darkvador/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 388, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/Users/darkvador/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 38, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/darkvador/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1709, in draw
    renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
  File "/Users/darkvador/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 135, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/Users/darkvador/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 38, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/darkvador/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2647, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
  File "/Users/darkvador/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 135, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/Users/darkvador/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 38, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/darkvador/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 619, in draw
    renderer, renderer.get_image_magnification())
  File "/Users/darkvador/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 881, in make_image
    unsampled=unsampled)
  File "/Users/darkvador/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 530, in _make_image
    np.asarray(alpha_channel, np.float32) * out_alpha * alpha,
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (740,740) (300,300)
```

I'm under macos-catalina, with python:

```
Python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 26 2020, 10:32:53) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
```

Note that the error does not occur if:

- I comment the `plt.show()`
- I use a constant `alpha`-value
- I run this piece of code under a classic python 3.6 from the linux distribution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [matplotlib 3.1.3 documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html?highlight=imshow#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow), the `alpha` keyword argument must be a scalar value.

You should update to Matplotlib 3.3.1, because giving an array for the `alpha` parameters must have been implemented in between these two versions.

Comment: Yes, since version 3.3.1. This is what my answer says.

Answer (score 2):

Your alpha array `alpha/alpha.max()` does not match the shape of the actual image array `test`. From the test code you provided, we can create an alpha array and successfully display it as an alpha-varying image with the code below. So you have to make sure the `alpha` array has the exact same shape as the `test` array.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test = np.random.random((300, 300))
alpha = test / test.max()
print(alpha)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(test, alpha = alpha)
plt.show()
```

producing the image below.

[image: imshow with alpha]

Comment: It was a typo that I just corrected .. sorry, but it actually does !

Comment: Do you mean that you still get an error on your side?

Comment: Yes ! Only under the environment I mentioned. As detailed, if I run it under python 3.6 from the linux distribution it works

Comment: OK, and what matplotlib version do you work with? I am with macos-catalina as well.

Comment: It's matplotlib 3.1.3. Is your python also 3.7 from anaconda ? Just noticed that my numpy version is only 1.16.4; I'll update it and check the error.

Comment: Alright, from the [matplotlib 3.1.3 documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html?highlight=imshow#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow), the `alpha` keyword argument must be a scalar still. You should update to Matplotlib 3.3.1, because they might have implemented this feature later. I will provide another answer then.

Comment: Indeed ! Damn, I checked that, but I too quickly so I didn't noticed the difference between 3.1.3 and 3.3.1 .. Thanks